# Is it possible to close a program via python?

Tags: python

I've opened a browser to view a web page

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)")
```

Would I be able to then close the browser after my code has ran?

Comment: what is your default browser and what os?

Comment: No you can't

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959314/is-it-possible-to-close-a-program-via-python

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's not pretty but you can do a native task kill

`os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM ie.exe")`

Comment: What if the default browser isn't ie? And what if there is another internet explorer window open?

Comment: more importantly what if the OP is not using windows

Comment: Indeed, I'm not a python expert and was thinking that the os.system command would translate to other operating systems.

Comment: really subprocess would be the way to go if you were going to call native commands

Comment: I agree its not pretty. But if you know the browser its in it'll do the trick

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way of doing this.  [The `webbrowser` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/webbrowser.html) does not expose an interface to close the browser, only to open URLs in an implementation-independent way.

To close the browser, you will need to find out what browser `webbrowser` is actually using, and perform browser- and operating system dependent actions.

If you don't need the system independence offered by `webbrowser`, you might want to start and stop your specific browser manually, for example using [the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html).   How to do this then depends on your choice of OS and browser.